# Attempt to compile Scipy on Android Termux Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, termux

I am deeply frustrated by rolling-releases of *Termux* with no regard to previous python releases and modules

Now I am compiling latest got version of *Scipy* but before that I am running

```
export BLAS=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libblas.so
export LAPACK=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/liblapack.so
export CC=clang
export CPP=clang++
python runtests.py -v
```

https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/runtests.html

There were some missing packages which I installed via *pip*
Following is the output & I need help here

```
Building, see build.log...
    ... build in progress (0:01:00.279236 elapsed)
Running from SciPy source directory.
scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py: all files up-to-date
scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py: all files up-to-date
Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx has not changed
scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx has not changed
scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx has not changed
scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx has not changed
scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx has not changed
scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx has not changed
scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx has not changed
scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx has not changed
scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx has not changed
scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx has not changed
scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx has not changed
scipy/io/matlab/_mio5_utils.pyx has not changed
scipy/io/matlab/_mio_utils.pyx has not changed
scipy/io/matlab/_streams.pyx has not changed
scipy/linalg/_cythonized_array_utils.pyx has not changed
scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in has not changed
scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_expm.pyx.in has not changed
scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx has not changed
scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx has not changed
scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx has not changed
scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx has not changed
scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx has not changed
scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx has not changed
scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in has not changed
scipy/optimize/tnc/_moduleTNC.pyx has not changed
scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx has not changed
scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx has not changed
scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx has not changed
scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx has not changed
scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx has not changed
scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx has not changed
scipy/spatial/_ckdtree.pyx has not changed
scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx has not changed
scipy/spatial/_qhull.pyx has not changed
scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx has not changed
scipy/spatial/transform/_rotation.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/_comb.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/_test_round.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx has not changed
scipy/special/cython_special.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_biasedurn.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_stats.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_boost/src/hypergeom_ufunc.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_boost/src/ncf_ufunc.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_levy_stable/levyst.pyx has not changed
scipy/stats/_unuran/unuran_wrapper.pyx has not changed
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:102: _ExperimentalProjectMetadata: Support for project metadata in `pyproject.toml` is still experimental and may be removed (or change) in future releases.
  warnings.warn(msg, _ExperimentalProjectMetadata)
Cythonizing sources
INFO: lapack_opt_info:
INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
INFO:
INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
INFO:
INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
INFO: C compiler: clang -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC

creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux/files
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz
INFO: compile options: '-c'
INFO: clang: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/source.c
INFO: clang /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/source.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lopenblas -o /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpw9i7rrqz/a.out
INFO:   FOUND:
INFO:     libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
INFO:     library_dirs = ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:     language = c
INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
INFO:
INFO:   FOUND:
INFO:     libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
INFO:     library_dirs = ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:     language = c
INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
INFO:
non-existing path in 'scipy/linalg': 'src/lapack_deprecations/LICENSE'
INFO: blas_opt_info:
INFO: blas_armpl_info:
INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
INFO:
INFO: blas_mkl_info:
INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
INFO:
INFO: blis_info:
INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
INFO:
INFO: openblas_info:
INFO: C compiler: clang -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC

creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux/files
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp
creating /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e
INFO: compile options: '-c'
INFO: clang: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/source.c
INFO: clang /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/source.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lopenblas -o /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp0139l74e/a.out
INFO:   FOUND:
INFO:     libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
INFO:     library_dirs = ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:     language = c
INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
INFO:
INFO:   FOUND:
INFO:     libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
INFO:     library_dirs = ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
INFO:     language = c
INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
INFO:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/setup.py", line 532, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/setup.py", line 528, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/setup.py", line 438, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1054, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1020, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 962, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/scipy/setup.py", line 18, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('optimize')
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1054, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1020, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 962, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/scipy/optimize/setup.py", line 130, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('_highs')
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1054, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1020, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 962, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/scipy/optimize/_highs/setup.py", line 63, in configuration
    _major_dot_minor = _get_version(
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/scipy/optimize/_highs/setup.py", line 50, in _get_version
    with open(CMakeLists, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/scipy/_lib/highs/CMakeLists.txt'

Build failed! (0:01:17.306152 elapsed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Clean Install Termux on Samsung Z Flip 4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDwxmF0Kn-Q

update

upgrade

apt install python  (3.11.1 was installed)

To manage and access files in termux then you must type the below command

termux-setup-storage

pkg install tur-repo

pkg install python-scipy

connected phone via usb to a computer and copied my python scripts to phone downloads folder

cp ~/storage/downloads/file.py ~/   to run programs from termux home.
You get Deprecation Warnings for interp2d which will be replaced in scipy
so add to stop them at the top.

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

The end. ps

All woks fine and tested on 2d interpolation arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that what you want is the latest version of Scipy working in Termux.**

I think you are making it difficult for yourself.
I managed to compile and install scipy 1.8.1 correctly for python 3.10.4 using only Termux.

First, get rid of all exports before installation. As a side note, if no `CC` env. variable is set, pip will use `aarch64-linux-android-clang` by default.

You don't need `libblas.so` and `liblapack.so` either.
It is indeed necessary to have the BLAS/LAPACK libraries when compiling Scipy, but you can simply get them by `pkg in openblas`.

Once done, a simple `pip install scipy` worked like a charm for me (it took me more than 15 minutes to build it, so be patient).

Hope it helps you ^^

Comment: I fail to install scipy following your steps with python 3.11

Comment: Scipy depends on Numpy and Ninja. To build Numpy you now need to specify MATHLIB environment variable (see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246892/370078 ). I admit that I can't anymore build Ninja ("easily"), it keeps failing `cmake --build . --target install --config Release --`.
You could try downloading Ninja, apply the patch https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/ninja then build it, but Idon't know if it will work. **Also, please say what are *your errors instead of "it does not work"***.

Comment: I have installed `ninja` by `pkg install ninja`, and installed `numpy`, but `pip install scipy` gives the same error as your `cmake ...`.

Comment: Use TUR repo ...it has builtin scipy

Answer (score 0):

Although I was unable to install Scipy via pip for Python 3.11, which is the current version used in Termux as of today, I managed to build Scipy 1.9.0 and install it manually.

Apart from some dependencies I installed via pkg, which were requested by the build system, such as pytest, I had to try with different versions of pip-installed libraries. The required libraries and versions that worked were:

```
beniget==0.4.1
Cython==0.29.32
distro==1.8.0
gast==0.5.3
meson==0.62.2
meson-python==0.7.0
mpmath==1.2.1
ninja==1.11.1
numpy==1.23.5
packaging==21.3
pip==22.3.1
ply==3.11
pybind11==2.9.2
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyproject-metadata==0.6.1
pythran==0.11.0
scikit-build==0.16.2
setuptools==65.6.3
tomli==2.0.1
wheel==0.37.1
```

I'm not sure if all of them are required. With them installed, I obtained the sources tarball for scipy-1.9.0, uncompressed it, and executed runtests.py (found in the root of the uncompressed tree).

After this, a working build of scipy was created in "build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/scipy", I copied it to the system package directory: "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/../usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/", and now I can use scipy again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the submodules as described in [Building Scipy from source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/building/index.html#building-from-source)

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

See also the related question and answer [Can't install Scipy from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407691/cant-install-scipy-from-source-in-ubuntu-focal-python-3-8-10-cant-find-s).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).